# Scala type inference limitations

Tags: scala, types

I am developing a ORM-style library on top of ReactiveMongo. Currently I've tried to implement a nested document representation - however I've been stuck with Scala's type inference for my class. I am quite new to Scala so every help is welcome.

This is my attempt:

```
trait MongoDocument[T <: MongoDocument[T]] {
  self: T =>

  val db: DefaultDB
  val collection: String

  var fields: List[MongoField[T,_]] = List.empty
  def apply(doc: TraversableBSONDocument): T = { // loads the content of supplied document
    fields.foreach { field =>
      doc.get(field.field).foreach(field.load(_))
    }
    this
  }
}
trait MongoMetaDocument[T <: MongoDocument[T]] extends MongoDocument[T] {
  self: T =>

  type DocType = T

  protected val clazz = this.getClass.getSuperclass
  def create: T = clazz.newInstance().asInstanceOf[T]

  def find(id: String): Future[Option[T]] = {
    db(collection).find(BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONObjectID(id)))
      .headOption().map(a => a.map(create.apply(_)))
  }
}

abstract class MongoField[Doc <: MongoDocument[Doc], T](doc: MongoDocument[Doc], val field: String) {
  var value: Option[T] = None

  def is: Option[T] = value
  def apply(in: T) { value = Some(in) }
  def unset() { value = None }

  def load(bson: BSONValue)

  doc.fields ::= this
}

class MongoInteger[Doc <: MongoDocument[Doc]](doc: Doc, field: String)
  extends MongoField[Doc, Int](doc, field) {

  def load(bson: BSONValue) { value = Try(bson.asInstanceOf[BSONNumberLike].toInt).toOption }
}

class MongoDoc[Doc <: MongoDocument[Doc], SubDocF <: MongoMetaDocument[SubDoc], SubDoc <: MongoDocument[SubDoc]](doc: Doc, field: String, meta: SubDocF)
  extends MongoField[Doc, SubDocF#DocType](doc, field) {

  def load(bson: BSONValue) {
    value = Try(bson.asInstanceOf[TraversableBSONDocument]).toOption.map { doc =>
       meta.create.apply(doc)
    }
  }
}
```

Assuming that I have following  code:

```
class SubEntity extends MongoDocument[SubEntity] {
  val db = Db.get
  val collection = ""

  val field = new MongoInteger(this, "field")
}
object SubEntity extends SubEntity with MongoMetaDocument[SubEntity]
```

I would like to write another entity as:

```
class Another extends MongoDocument[Another] {
  val db = Db.get
  val collection = "test"

  val subEntity = new MongoDoc(this, "subEntity", SubEntity)
}
object Another extends Another with MongoMetaDocument[Another]
```

Where `Db.get` just returns a `DefaultDB`.

However Scala cannot infer the types for the `MongoDoc` instance even though I thought they might be inferrable (as `Doc` is easily inferred, `SubDocF` can be inferred to `SubEntity.type` and as `SubEntity` mixins just `MongoMetaDocument[SubEntity]` then the `SubDoc` type has to be `SubEntity`). If I use following code, everything goes just fine:

```
val subEntity = new MongoDoc[Another,SubEntity.type,SubEntity](this, "subEntity", SubEntity)
```

Is there some solution that the types need not be set explicitly? As I need to build an instance of a class that extends from `MongoDocument` trait, I was trying to solve that by using the metaobject that has the `create` method.

Currently the only workaround I've come up with makes use of `implicitly` but that would make the entity definition a bit more nasty.

Thank you for helping me to sort this out (or for giving me some hint how to arrange my class hierarchy that this won't be a problem)

Answer (score 2):

You'll get better type inference if you get rid of the "F-bounded Polymorphism".  (that is when you are finding yourself writing type arguments of the form "T <: Foo[T]"), and instead use abstract type members in the traits which are reified in the concrete classes.

You'll find that inference works here:

```
trait MongoDocument
  type DocType <: MongoDocument

  def apply(doc: TraversableBSONDocument): DocType = ??? // loads the content of supplied document
}
trait MongoMetaDocument extends MongoDocument {

  protected val clazz = this.getClass.getSuperclass
  def create: DocType = clazz.newInstance().asInstanceOf[DocType]

  def find(id: String): Future[Option[DocType]] = ???
}

abstract class MongoField[Doc <: MongoDocument, T](doc: MongoDocument, field: String) {
  type DocType <: MongoDocument
  var value: Option[T]

  def is: Option[T] = value
  def apply(in: T) { value = Some(in) }
  def unset() { value = None }

  def load(bson: BSONValue)

}

class MongoDoc[Doc <: MongoDocument, SubDocF <: MongoMetaDocument, SubDoc <: MongoDocument](doc: Doc, field: String, meta: SubDocF)
  extends MongoField[Doc, SubDocF#DocType](doc, field) {
  type DocType = Doc

  def load(bson: BSONValue) {
    value = Try(bson.asInstanceOf[TraversableBSONDocument]).toOption.map { doc =>
       ???
    }
  }
}

class SubEntity extends MongoDocument {
  type DocType = SubEntity
  ???
}
object SubEntity extends SubEntity with MongoMetaDocument

class Another extends MongoDocument {
  type DocType = Another
  val subEntity = new MongoDoc(this, "subEntity", SubEntity)
}
object Another extends Another with MongoMetaDocument
```

Comment: I have tried to rewrite my implementation according to your answer and I have run in different problems. There is no limitation on the type of `MongoDocument#DocType` and user of the library can therefore specify entity `Another` with `DocType=SubEntity` (resulting at least in runtime exceptions in casting). Moreover the `MongoDocument.apply` method tries to be chainable and returns therefore `this` which doesn't compile as `this` is just of type `MongoDocument`. (and the missing assumption that `this` is not an instance of `MongoDocument#Doctype` breaks my code in different places as well)

Comment: I have changed the code in my question so that it is more apparent where the problem appears. (And thank you for your answer!)

Comment: The same limitation on DocType exists here as it does in your example.  That it must be a sub-type of MongoDocument.  In your case you think in your head about this knowing that the indication is that Another must be specified as Another extends MongoDocument[Another], but Another extends MongoDocument[SubEntity] is still allowed in your example, and yes, in either case, we are allowing people to write malicious classes, but there isn't a good way to prevent that and still get the return type polymorphism you are hoping for in a type safe way.

Comment: MongoDocument.apply has return type DocType not MongoDocument in my example.

Comment: Not really. In my case `class Another extends MongoDocument[SubEntity]` is not allowed thanks to the `self: T =>` construct in the beginning of the trait definition. Trying to do so would yield an error regarding nonconformant self-type. That construct also "changes" the type of `this` as in case I introduce the self-type, `this` has type `T` (and not `MongoDocument` as in your case)